# Garage in Breaking Bad

Tags: breaking-bad

Why Walt always parked the car outside the garage? because he had a huge garage!

[image]

Is this normal in USA?

Comment: yes, it's normal--especially in climates where it doesn't snow. In those regions of the US the garage is often used as a storage area/workshop instead. Cars don't care if they are left out in the rain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because most of us here in USA use our garage for storing useless crap or lawn mowers, tools, workbenches, etc. Breaking Bad's location was in New Mexico in a desert climate. In a snowy climate or rainy climate many do use garages for their cars. In a mostly sunny climate, there is no (not much) need.

Comment: *"In a mostly sunny climate, there is no need."*  Tell that to an Aussie.  It gets so hot here that parking spaces are not ranked optimal by their proximity to the destination, but for the availability of shade.. ;) +1 for your (localized/relevant) insight.

Comment: *"..most of us here in USA use our garage for storing useless crap or lawn mowers, tools, workbenches, **etc.**"*  .. as part of the 'etc.' I was just reminded of a scene early on in the series where Walter is reviewing the equipment Jesse collected for their first cook and had stored in *his garage..*  I'm pretty sure a car would not have fit in the garage at that moment.

Comment: Great observation Andrew..but I am sure as always..Walt would have found a way.. hehe